# SciFi book about Domes

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, hard-sci-fi, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for the title of a book from 80s/90s.  Some apocalyptic event and people live in domes. Different domes are for different things. Girl lives in one dome and wants to go to the Art dome to do drawing/set making for plays and things.  You have to work for XX amount of years before you can be offered citizenship if you are worthy.  If you aren't you can be sent "outside" as your home dome does not have to take you back.

There is this travelling band of actors from an island that is/was immune to whatever disaster happened.  Its called Tuatatu or something like that.  The girl falls in love with one of the actors.

I thought it was called Reunion but I'm not sure.  Thank you.

Comment: Talk about all those domes reminded me of Bio-Dome with Pauly Shore. Haha

Comment: Reminded me of "City of Gold and Lead". Link: http://a.co/5nRlzBe